# Spring Integration OutBoundGateway enhance the exception message

Tags: spring-integration

I am using class like below to make SOAP call to external webservice.

```
public class MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway extends SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway {

     private String externalServiceName;

     @Override
     protected Object doHandle(String uri, final Message<?> requestMessage, final WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback) {       

     try {
        Message<?> responseMessage = (Message<?>) super.doHandle(uri, requestMessage, new MySampleWebServiceMessageCallback(requestCallback, session,mapHeaders));            

        } catch (RuntimeException t) {
          ..         
         throw new MessageHandlingException(requestMessage, "Error Occurred at External Service: " + this.externalServiceName, t);
        }
```

I want to add additional info to exception like external Service name so that when error-channel get the exception, I can parse the message to get external service name. However, I get generic `MessageHandlingException` in the `error-channel` like this:

```
gateway.GatewayFacade - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [(inner bean)#30]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
```

Please let me know what I can do to add some additional details to exception, without having to wrap the exception with another exception.

Full Stack Trace:

```
2015-11-30 15:19:12,445 WARN  [main] {} org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: Error Occurred for External Service: Retrieve
    at com.myPackage.ws.outbound.MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:161)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.exchange(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.RequestReplyMessageHandlerAdapter.handleRequestMessage(RequestReplyMessageHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
    at com.myPackage.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade.process(GatewayFacade.java:67)
    at com.myPackage.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade.process(GatewayFacade.java:58)
    at com.myPackage.springIntegration.MySpringIntegrationTest.verifyErrorResponseWhenRetrieveFailsWithSoapFault(MySpringIntegrationTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: 1929|Application|This is an error message.
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:89)
    at com.MyPack.ws.outbound.MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:141)
    ... 107 more
2015-11-30 15:19:12,445 WARN  [main] {} com.myPack.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [(inner bean)#30]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
    at com.myPack.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade.process(GatewayFacade.java:67)
    at com.myPack.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade.process(GatewayFacade.java:58)
    at com.springIntegration.MySpringIntegrationTest.verifyErrorResponseWhenRetrieveFailsWithSoapFault(MySpringIntegrationTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: 1929|Application|This is an error message.
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:89)
    at com.myPack.ws.outbound.MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MySampleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.exchange(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.RequestReplyMessageHandlerAdapter.handleRequestMessage(RequestReplyMessageHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    ... 74 more
```

Here is what I noticed. If the gateway has `error-channel` defined like below, I get the exception in the `error-channel` as I expect.

```
<int:gateway request-channel="retrieve_external" error-channel="exception_errorChannel" />
```

However, I want to define `error-channel` at the top level.

```
<bean id="gatewayAdapter" class="com.myPack.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade">
  <property name="requestChannel" ref="my_Requests" />
  <property name="replyChannel" ref="my_response" />
  <property name="errorChannel" ref="exception_errorChannel" />
</bean>
```

---

```
public class GatewayFacade extends MessagingGatewaySupport implements GatewayAdapter, BeanNameAware {  .. }
```

With this way, `MessagingGatewaySupport` class looks that `error-channel` is `null`, and rethrows the original cause, which again gets wrapped into generic `MessageHandlingException`, which is why I loose the original `MessageHandlingException` I throw.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working as you describe; the code concerned (in `AbstractMessageHandler`) is:

```
if (e instanceof MessagingException) {
    throw (MessagingException) e;
}
throw new MessageHandlingException(message, "error occurred in message handler [" + this + "]", e);
```

i.e. since you are throwing a `MessageHandlingException`, it should just be re-thrown. So it looks like you might be throwing some other `MessageHandlingException` that's not in the `MessagingException` hierarchy.

Can you show the complete stack trace?

Comment: `org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: Error Occurred for ExternalService: Retrieve..
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: WARN  [main] {}myPackage.rest.gateway.GatewayFacade - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [(inner bean)#30]
 at AbstractMessageHandler ....... Caused by: SoapFaultClientException`

Comment: Nope, I see both exceptions in the logs; one with My message and other without my message, which is the one going to error-channel. It seems like AbstractMessageHandler is getting root cause and then wrapping it up with MessageHandlingException

Comment: I need to see the __complete__ stack trace for both exceptions - don't try to put them in a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: Is there anything that I could to get the actual exception thrown to the error-channel defined at the GatewayAdapter without having to wrap the exception with some other exception?

Comment: The exception unwrapping is done in the [`GatewayProxyFactoryBean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/gateway/GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java#L432) which invokes a `MessagingGatewaySupport`. Since you are using the MGS directly, you lose that code - you need to implement the unwrap in your subclass.